# open slider on click of image button

Tags: android, slider

i have some problem

[image]

this the footer bar of my android build now when i want that when i click on i button then slider bar should be open with another buttons like

[image]

how can i do this in android

i have try some work using alert dialog but its not working

any one have idea how can i do that

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hey anand can u give me some peace of code for animation.
and now are you working with CDN

Comment: yes you right, how yuo got that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should first have a slide_right_in.xml in your anim folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0"  android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

and slide_right_out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p"  android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

in your case you need left in and out animation so you should change above code as per need.
and then load animation in a animation object, then start it just before of setting visibility in above answer:

```
 Animation slide_right_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,  R.anim.slide_right_in);
 toggle_bar.startAnimation(slide_right_in);
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do something like this is to have a layout that contains the row of buttons you want to show or hide. You can then use an OnClickListener to set the button clicks to show or hide the layout. So something like this in the Activity could work:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button toggleButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toggle_button);

    //Set click listener to change the bar visiblity
    toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LinearLayout bar = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.toggle_bar);
            int visibility = bar.getVisibility();

            //Hide or show the bar according to it's current visibility
            if (visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

    });                   
}
```

And the simple example layout main.xml could look a bit like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50.0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/toggle_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Toggle visibility"
    />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toggle_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Button1"
        />
        <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Button2"
        />
        <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Button2"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you also need to animate the button row when the visibility changes, you should probably look into [animation resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html).

Comment: Thanks buddy its woks fine. you save my lots of time.